# Postgres 9.4: COPY with transformation step?

Tags: postgresql

I have some very large CSV files and I am working with Postgres 9.4. I am using [Postgres's COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) to import them into my database efficiently. This works fine:

```
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    copy_str = "COPY mytable(presentation_code,quantity,"
    copy_str += "processing_date,price_per_unit) FROM STDIN "
    copy_str += "WITH DELIMITER AS ','"
    file_obj = open(filename)
    cursor.copy_expert(copy_str, file_obj)
    try:
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as err:
        print 'EXCEPTION:', err
```

The issue is that I have to run some transformation steps on the data files *before* they are suitable for COPY. These include reordering the fields, converting strings to floats, transforming dates so they are suitable for Postgres, and calculating some values (though I could possibly skip this last step):

```
for row in reader:
    presentation_code = row[0].strip()
    quantity = int(row[1])
    period = row[9]
    processing_date = period[:4] + '-' + period[4:] + '-01'
    if row[4]:
        price_per_unit = actual_cost / float(row[4])
    else:
        price_per_unit = 0
    output = [presentation_code, quantity, processing_date, price_per_unit]
    writer.writerow(output)
```

Is there any Postgres tool that would let me do these two steps (transformation, then COPY) in a single command? Or is this just a necessary step?

Comment: If you can relax the "single command" requirement, a common approach would be to `COPY` into an intermediate temp table, with all columns defined as `TEXT`, and then do the transformation/import with an `INSERT INTO mytable SELECT ...`

Comment: @NickBarnes Thanks, but I'd like to avoid individual `INSERT` commands, these are large files (5GB of CSV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write your trasformation as a program which get each row from its standard input to the standard output, then use it as filter for the `copy` command itself. See the manual page of copy for the details (look at the "program" part): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html. Note that the program will be run as "postgres" user (if you want to run it from a client application, you could use the \copy command of psql, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html).